# How to fetch Artifact from central repo for installation using Install4j

Tags: install4j

I am trying to build my application installer using install4j.

As part of installation , we would like to fetch our product build artifacts from central repo for installation.

Just want to know if we can achieve this with install4j and if yes any pointer would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

install4j has a "Download file" action that lets you download arbitrary URLs as part of the installation. You can add that action to the "Installation" screen of your installer on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step.